# Jquery Latter Shuffle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm try to animate (Shuffle) Pre-Typed Text using This plugin **[Text Shuffle Plugin](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/.)**

But issue is, this is only work when we type in text box. I want to do that when page load.

Here is its Online demo link. **[DEMO](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/)**

Here Is Fiddle Link. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lv5/1/)**

Unfortunately  I am unable to create its fiddle. I just want the onload effect on pre define 's ID

**JS Code**

```
    $.fn.shuffleLetters = function(prop){

    var options = $.extend({
    "step"  : 8,    // How many times should the letters be changed
    "fps"   : 25,   // Frames Per Second
    "text"  : ""    // Use this text instead of the contents
    },prop)

    return this.each(function(){

    var el = $(this),
        str = "";

    if(options.text) {
        str = options.text.split('');
    }
    else {
        str = el.text().split('');
    }

    // The types array holds the type for each character;
    // Letters holds the positions of non-space characters;

    var types = [],
        letters = [];

    // Looping through all the chars of the string

    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

        var ch = str[i];

        if(ch == " "){
        types[i] = "space";
        continue;
        }
        else if(/[a-z]/.test(ch)){
        types[i] = "lowerLetter";
        }
        else if(/[A-Z]/.test(ch)){
        types[i] = "upperLetter";
        }
        else {
        types[i] = "symbol";
        }

        letters.push(i);
    }

    el.html("");            

    // Self executing named function expression:

    (function shuffle(start){

        // This code is run options.fps times per second
        // and updates the contents of the page element

        var i,
        len = letters.length,
        strCopy = str.slice(0); // Fresh copy of the string

        if(start>len){
        return;
        }

        // All the work gets done here
        for(i=Math.max(start,0); i < len; i++){

        // The start argument and options.step limit
        // the characters we will be working on at once

        if( i < start+options.step){
            // Generate a random character at this position
            strCopy[letters[i]] = randomChar(types[letters[i]]);
        }
        else {
            strCopy[letters[i]] = "";
        }
        }

        el.text(strCopy.join(""));

        setTimeout(function(){

        shuffle(start+1);

        },1000/options.fps);

    })(-options.step);

    });
};
```

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: What have you tried?
You linked us to a demo, can't you use the source code from that page?

Comment: @epascarello wait I update fiddlle link, but its not working

Comment: @Cerbrus  wait I update fiddlle link, but its not working

Comment: I'm getting: `GET http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/assets/js/jquery.shuffleLetters.js 403 (Forbidden)`
`GET http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/assets/js/script.js 403 (Forbidden)` In the console. The scripts aren't loading. (Apparently, you can't include them in external sites)

Comment: @Cerbrus Working for me. you can load them via my fiddle. "http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/assets/js/jquery.shuffleLetters.js"
and I update script.js in fiddle.

Comment: @Cerbrus Fiddle Updated. Now working fine http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lv5/1/

Comment: Yea, the fiddle works, now. Now what's the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46687/discussion-between-shivam-pandya-and-cerbrus)

Comment: @Cerbrus The Problem is first div load auto on page load, but for other we need to enter in text. I'm going to use this in carousel. so first div need to work on load and another on carousel change